# Are there sorting algorithms that respect final position restrictions and run in O(n log n) time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I'm looking for a sorting algorithm that honors a min and max range for each element<sup>1</sup>. The problem domain is a recommendations engine that combines a set of business rules (the restrictions) with a recommendation score (the value). If we have a recommendation we want to promote (e.g. a special product or deal) or an announcement we want to appear near the top of the list (e.g. "This is super important, remember to verify your email address to participate in an upcoming promotion!") or near the bottom of the list (e.g. "If you liked these recommendations, click here for more..."), they will be curated with certain position restriction in place. For example, this should always be the top position, these should be in the top 10, or middle 5 etc. This curation step is done ahead of time and remains fixed for a given time period and for business reasons must remain very flexible.

Please don't question the business purpose, UI or input validation. I'm just trying to implement the algorithm in the constraints I've been given. Please treat this as an academic question. I will endeavor to provide a rigorous problem statement, and feedback on all other aspects of the problem is very welcome.

---

So if we were sorting `char`s, our data would have a structure of

```
struct {
  char value;
  Integer minPosition;
  Integer maxPosition;
}
```

Where `minPosition` and `maxPosition` may be null (unrestricted). If this were called on an algorithm where all positions restrictions were null, or all `minPosition`s were 0 or less and all `maxPositions` were equal to or greater than the size of the list, then the output would just be `char`s in ascending order.

This algorithm would only reorder two elements if the `minPosition` and `maxPosition` of both elements would not be violated by their new positions. An insertion-based algorithm which promotes items to the top of the list and reorders the rest has obvious problems in that every later element would have to be revalidated after each iteration; in my head, that rules out such algorithms for having *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* complexity, but I won't rule out such algorithms without considering evidence to the contrary, if presented.

In the output list, certain elements will be out of order with regard to their value, if and only if the set of position constraints dictates it. These outputs are still **valid**.

- A **valid** list is any list where all elements are in a position that does not conflict with their constraints.
- An **optimal** list is a list which cannot be reordered to more closely match the natural order without violating one or more position constraint. An invalid list is never optimal. I don't have a strict definition I can spell out for 'more closely matching' between one ordering or another. However, I think it's fairly easy to let intuition guide you, or choose something similar to a [distance metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric).
  Multiple optimal orderings may exist if multiple inputs have the same value. You could make an argument that the above paragraph is therefore incorrect, because either one can be reordered to the other without violating constraints and therefore neither can be optimal. However, any rigorous distance function would treat these lists as identical, with the same distance from the natural order and therefore reordering the identical elements is allowed (because it's a no-op).
  I would call such outputs the correct, sorted order which respects the position constraints, but several commentators pointed out that we're not *really* returning a sorted list, so let's stick with 'optimal'.

---

For example, the following are a input lists (in the form of `<char>(<minPosition>:<maxPosition>)`, where `Z(1:1)` indicates a `Z` that must be at the front of the list and `M(-:-)` indicates an `M` that may be in any position in the final list and the natural order (sorted by value only) is `A...M...Z`) and their optimal orders.

```
Input order
A(1:1) D(-:-) C(-:-) E(-:-) B(-:-)
Optimal order
A      B      C      D      E
```

This is a trivial example to show that the natural order prevails in a list with no constraints.

---

```
Input order
E(1:1) D(2:2) C(3:3) B(4:4) A(5:5)
Optimal order
E      D      C      B      A
```

This example is to show that a fully constrained list is output in the same order it is given. The input is already a **valid** and **optimal** list. The algorithm should still run in *O(n log n)* time for such inputs. (Our initial solution is able to short-circuit any fully constrained list to run in linear time; I added the example both to drive home the definitions of optimal and valid and because some swap-based algorithms I considered handled this as the worse case.)

---

```
Input order
E(1:1) C(-:-) B(1:5) A(4:4) D(2:3)
Optimal Order
E      B      D      A      C
```

`E` is constrained to `1:1`, so it is first in the list even though it has the lowest value. `A` is similarly constrained to `4:4`, so it is also out of natural order. `B` has essentially identical constraints to `C` and may appear anywhere in the final list, but `B` will be before `C` because of value. `D` may be in positions 2 or 3, so it appears after `B` because of natural ordering but before `C` because of its constraints.

Note that the final order is correct despite being wildly different from the natural order (which is still `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`). As explained in the previous paragraph, nothing in this list can be reordered without violating the constraints of one or more items.

---

```
Input order
B(-:-) C(2:2) A(-:-) A(-:-)
Optimal order
A(-:-) C(2:2) A(-:-) B(-:-)
```

`C` remains unmoved because it already in its only valid position. `B` is reordered to the end because its value is less than both `A`'s. In reality, there will be additional fields that differentiate the two `A`'s, but from the standpoint of the algorithm, they are identical and preserving OR reversing their input ordering is an optimal solution.

---

```
Input order
A(1:1) B(1:1) C(3:4) D(3:4) E(3:4)
Undefined output
```

This input is invalid for two reasons: 1) `A` and `B` are both constrained to position 1 and 2) `C`, `D`, and `E` are constrained to a range than can only hold 2 elements. In other words, the ranges `1:1` and `3:4` are *over-constrained*. However, the consistency and legality of the constraints are enforced by UI validation, so it's officially not the algorithms problem if they are incorrect, and the algorithm can return a best-effort ordering OR the original ordering in that case. Passing an input like this to the algorithm may be considered [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); anything can happen. So, for the rest of the question...

---

- **All input lists will have elements that are initially in valid positions.**
- **The sorting algorithm itself can assume the constraints are valid and an optimal order exists.**<sup>2</sup>

We've currently settled on a customized selection sort (with runtime complexity of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*) and reasonably proved that it works for all inputs whose position restrictions are valid and consistent (e.g. not overbooked for a given position or range of positions).

Is there a sorting algorithm that is guaranteed to return the optimal final order and run in better than *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time complexity?<sup>3</sup>

I feel that a library standard sorting algorithm could be modified to handle these constrains by providing a custom comparator that accepts the candidate destination position for each element. This would be equivalent to the current position of each element, so maybe modifying the value holding class to include the current position of the element and do the extra accounting in the comparison (`.equals()`) and swap methods would be sufficient.

However, the more I think about it, an algorithm that runs in *O(n log n)* time could not work correctly with these restrictions. Intuitively, such algorithms are based on running *n* comparisons *log n* times. The *log n* is achieved by leveraging a divide and conquer mechanism, which only compares certain candidates for certain positions.

In other words, input lists with valid position constraints (i.e. counterexamples) exist for any *O(n log n)* sorting algorithm where a candidate element would be compared with an element (or range in the case of Quicksort and variants) with/to which it could not be swapped, and therefore would never move to the correct final position. If that's too vague, I can come up with a counter example for mergesort and quicksort.

In contrast, an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* sorting algorithm makes exhaustive comparisons and can always move an element to its correct final position.

**To ask an actual question:** Is my intuition correct when I reason that an *O(n log n)* sort is not guaranteed to find a valid order? If so, can you provide more concrete proof? If not, why not? Is there other existing research on this class of problem?

---

<sup>1</sup>: I've not been able to find a set of search terms that points me in the direction of any concrete classification of such sorting algorithm or constraints; that's why I'm asking some basic questions about the complexity. If there is a term for this type of problem, please post it up.

<sup>2</sup>: Validation is a separate problem, worthy of its own investigation and algorithm. I'm pretty sure that the existence of a valid order can be proven in linear time:

1. Allocate array of tuples of length equal to your list. Each tuple is an integer counter *k* and a double value *v* for the relative assignment weight.
2. Walk the list, adding the fractional value of each elements position constraint to the corresponding range and incrementing its counter by 1 (e.g. range 2:5 on a list of 10 adds 0.4 to each of 2,3,4, and 5 on our tuple list, incrementing the counter of each as well)
3. Walk the tuple list and
4. If no entry has value *v* greater than the sum of the series from 1 to *k* of *1/k*, a valid order exists.
5. If there is such a tuple, the position it is in is over-constrained; throw an exception, log an error, use the doubles array to correct the problem elements etc.

**Edit:** This validation algorithm itself is actually *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Worst case, every element has the constraints `1:n`, you end up walking your list of *n* tuples *n* times. This is still irrelevant to the scope of the question, because in the real problem domain, the constraints are enforced once and don't change.

Determining that a given list is in valid order is even easier. Just check each elements current position against its constraints.

<sup>3</sup>: This is admittedly a little bit premature optimization. Our initial use for this is for fairly small lists, but we're eyeing expansion to longer lists, so if we can optimize now we'd get small performance gains now and large performance gains later. And besides, my curiosity is piqued and if there is research out there on this topic, I would like to see it and (hopefully) learn from it.

Comment: The trouble with these constraints is that it isn't even guaranteed that a valid order exists. If you could prove that it's impossible to prove the existence of a valid order with fewer than O(n*n) comparisons, you've got your answer.

Comment: `The consistency and legality of the constraints are enforced by UI validation, so it's officially not the algorithms problem if they are incorrect`.  That's usually a recipe for trouble.  Never trust the UI, and never assume it will not be totally replaced by something different.

Comment: Or imagine a worst-case scenario: your elements should be sorted in ascending order but the smallest element is restricted to the last position, the second smallest to the second last and so on.

Comment: @biziclop I started to address that; edited to make it clear you can assume there is a valid order. I'm sure that the constraints can be checked in linear time (allocate array of doubles of length equal to your list, walk the list, add the fractional value of each position constraint to the corresponding range (e.g. range 2:5 on a list of 10 ads 0.4 to each of 2,3,4, and 5), walk the doubles and if no entry is greater than 1, a valid order exists; if not, throw an exception, log an error, use the doubles array to correct the problem elements etc.), so let's discount that possibility for now.

Comment: The problem is also that, as you describe it, fixed points cascade and can drastically affect the validity of moving later points. I could have a point where moving it to its final position would be valid, but doing so would violoate the validity of some of the points after that position. How do you address that? In other words it might be perfectly valid to swap a point when I get to it, but in the final sort order it might no longer be valid.

Comment: @EricJ. I'm not trusting the UI, but validation is a separate problem from sorting, so let's keep the question focused on the algorithm.

Comment: What's wrong with (1) Sort in O(n log n); (2) verify constraints in O(n); (3) report success and sorted result, or failure and empty result. This clearly is an O(n log n) performer.

Comment: @Aruisdante that's a problem for certain algorithms (Insertion Sort comes to mind), but swap-based algorithms could only potentially invalidate the two candidate elements (which is a different problem that I think rules them out, as the question covers).

Comment: @PatrickM Sure, but then you could wind up with points in completely arbitrary states (the last swap that didn't violate a constraint). It sounds like the OP wants either the point to be in its final sorted position, or in its original position. Not in some pseudo-sorted position that is different from both its original position and normal final position.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens failure is not an option :-) We could do that first to try it, I suppose, and fallback to a slower algorithm... more costly from dev time, but potentially worth it.

Comment: What happens when the constraints aren't valid for a sorted result if *failure is not an option*?

Comment: @aruisdante I am the OP :-) Re. 1st comment: Validation is a separate problem; I'm only interested in running time complexity and correctness. Re. 2nd comment, the algorithm should never return a list with any item that is in violation of its own position constraints; I will not use such an algorithm. An algorithm that *always* returns a valid, optimal list is superior to one that finds a suboptimal result. The question is whether or not there is such an algorithm that runs in less than *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time.

Comment: It might be helpful to understand the actual domain problem being addressed by this algorithm.

Comment: 1) Sort O(nlogn)  2) create a mapping from old to sorted positions O(n) 3) traverse each cycle in the mapping and if position maps outside its range the cycle fails and none in the cycle move O(n). Is there something wrong with this? Do you have duplicate values? could you provide the O(n^2) solution, I don't find the description clear.

Comment: Could you please add a mathematically precise problem statement? IMO, calling it "sorting" is not really good if a non-sorted array is a valid result sometimes.

Comment: @PatrickM: I think just finding valid slots for all the data is O(n^2), completely ignoring the "sorting".

Comment: @PatrickM using your struct definition, if your initial array is `({'c',0,0}, {'b',0,2}, {'a',0,2})`, what is your desired output?  `({'c',0,0}, {'a',0,2}, {'b',0,2})`, even though `c` is out of order?

Comment: Examples added; you have the right of it Degustaf. And I agree, calling it sorting is imprecise. That's why I called it sorting with restrictions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: All the question about proofs are unanswerable here. To prove something, we need to know exactly what we are trying to prove. It is not possible to prove or disprove a correctness of an algorithm if there is no precise definition of correctness. The only way to make it answerable is to start with a rigorous problem statement.

Comment: By the way, how did you prove that an `O(n^2)` algorithm is correct? What definition of correctness did you use for this proof?(if there wasn't such a definition, it could not  be a proof).

Comment: @PatrickM I get that the ranges are a hard constraint and a sorted list is optimal. But since a sorted list is not always valid it is not clear how to measure the quality of a solution. If I have two solutions that satisfy the placement constraints and neither is perfectly sorted, how do I evaluate which is better?

Comment: @rpattiso: Specifically, it sounds like as long as I make it fast, I can ignore the sorting altogether.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, without the sorting it can be done in `O(n*log n)` time

Comment: @PatrickM: I'm not sure that method of verifying the constraints works. Where does the 0.4 come from? Is it 4(number of positions in range of constraint) divided by 10(number of elements in total)? If so, constraining all 10 elements to the first slot in the array would leave no elements with >1 total, and yet clearly this can't be satisfied! If that's not the way you intend it to work, can you explain more clearly? (The question is valid either way, though!)

Comment: @MooingDuck I added a definition of the output and various examples. Hopefully the 'optimal' order is rigorous enough.

Comment: @psmears you were right about the validation, of course. It was also always a polynomial solution. But let's set it aside as it's still tangential to the problem.

Comment: @PatrickM: Actually you can do it in linear time if you're cunning - but I agree it's tangential :)

Comment: I don't think you'll get far with sorting here. To me, your problem is essentially a [Constraint Satisfaction Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), as the positional constraints have priority over the "value". Unfortunately, these problems are NP-complete, though there are some clever algorithms using domain-specific heuristics that make large problems solvable.

Comment: @FranzD.: No, ignoring the sorting part it's essentially a scheduling problem, which can be solved in `n log n` time.

Answer (score 1):

On the existence of a solution: You can view this as a bipartite digraph with one set of vertices (U) being the k values, and the other set (V) the k ranks (1 to k), and an arc from each vertex in U to its valid ranks in V. Then the existence of a solution is equivalent to the maximum matching being a bijection. One way to check for this is to add a source vertex with an arc to each vertex in U, and a sink vertex with an arc from each vertex in V. Assign each edge a capacity of 1, then find the max flow. If it's k then there's a solution, otherwise not.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem

--edit-- O(k^3) solution: First sort to find the sorted rank of each vertex (1-k). Next, consider your values and ranks as 2 sets of k vertices, U and V, with weighted edges from each vertex in U to all of its legal ranks in V. The weight to assign each edge is the distance from the vertices rank in sorted order. E.g., if U is 10 to 20, then the natural rank of 10 is 1. An edge from value 10 to rank 1 would have a weight of zero, to rank 3 would have a weight of 2. Next, assume all missing edges exist and assign them infinite weight. Lastly, find the "MINIMUM WEIGHT PERFECT MATCHING" in O(k^3).

http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/matching-notes.pdf

This does not take advantage of the fact that the legal ranks for each element in U are contiguous, which may help get the running time down to O(k^2).

Comment: Idea to think about if there is a solution: Find the natural sort, then instead of assigning each edge a capacity of 1, assign capacities that favor the natural order in some way.

Comment: This is a meaty answer that's given me a lot to think about. I need some clarification on "**maximum matching being a bijection**". If you're talking about a mathematical [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) as a 1-to-1 mapping, then what is the maximum matching? Because the set of vertices from U to V as you initially describe can have way more links than a bijection.

Comment: @PatrickM A bijection is a subset of the edges such that each vertex is incident to exactly one edge. E.g., if U = {a, b} and V = {x, y} and the edge set is all edges from U to V, then one bijection is {ax, by}, and another is {ay, bx}.

Comment: that's what I thought you meant. So what does **maximum matching** mean? Because the basic set of values 1 to k which are valid for all k ranks is a valid list with a trivial solution, but the set of vertices from values to ranks is an exhaustive set of combinations. Using the vars but with a & b being both valid for both x & y, the edges from U to V are {ax, ay, bx, by} and the final sorted (lexicographic) order is (a,b). If the edge set were {ax, ay, bx}, {ay, bx, by} or {ay, bx}, the final order would be (b,a). Only one of those sets is a bijection. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for all the jargon -- I put it there so you'd know the right things to search for if you wanted more answers. A matching is a set of edges that don't share any vertices. A maximum matching is one that's as large as possible. A maximum matching being a bijection means that the matching that's as large as possible uses all the vertices. The reason I'm translating your problem to it's equivalent graph theory problem is so you can use the tools of graph theory & network flows to help solve it (though I was only able to get a cubic solution).

Comment: No need to apologize my friend! I need to learn the jargon. I know Graph Theory is where the rubber meets the road for a lot of CS, but I don't know the stuff that well. The set of edges {ax, ay, bx} would reduce to a matching of {ay, bx} because ax shares vertices with the other two edges. Since this is a bijection, we have a valid solution. Do I have that right? Then, determining which of the set of possible maximum matchings has an ordering closest to the natural ordering is equivalent to finding the optimal order.

Comment: @PatrickM You got it! The rest of my answer assigns weights to the edges to favor better orderings, and uses the 'maximum flow' algorithm to find the best ordering. Problem is it isn't fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what a coworker and I have come up with. I think it's an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* solution that returns a valid, optimal order if one exists, and a closest-possible effort if the initial ranges were over-constrained. I just tweaked a few things about the implementation and we're still writing tests, so there's a chance it doesn't work as advertised. This over-constrained condition is detected fairly easily when it occurs.

To start, things are simplified if you normalize your inputs to have all non-null constraints. In linear time, that is:

- for each item in input
- if an item doesn't have a minimum position, set it to 1
- if an item doesn't have a maximum position, set it to the length of your list

The next goal is to construct a list of ranges, each containing all of the candidate elements that have that range and ordered by the remaining capacity of the range, ascending so ranges with the fewest remaining spots are on first, then by start position of the range, then by end position of the range. This can be done by creating a set of such ranges, then sorting them in *O(n log n)* time with a simple comparator.

For the rest of this answer, a range will be a simple object like so

```
class Range<T> implements Collection<T> {
   int startPosition;
   int endPosition;
   Collection<T> items;

   public int remainingCapacity() {
       return endPosition - startPosition + 1 - items.size();
   }

   // implement Collection<T> methods, passing through to the items collection
   public void add(T item) {
       // Validity checking here exposes some simple cases of over-constraining
       // We'll catch these cases with the tricky stuff later anyways, so don't choke
       items.add(item);
   }
}
```

If an element `A` has range `1:5`, construct a `range(1,5)`  object and add `A` to its elements. This range has remaining capacity of *5 - 1 + 1 - 1* (max - min + 1 - size) *= 4*. If an element `B` has range `1:5`, add it to your existing range, which now has capacity 3.

Then it's a relatively simple matter of picking the best element that fits each position `1 => k` in turn. Iterate your ranges in their sorted order, keeping track of the best eligible element, with the twist that you stop looking if you've reached a range that has a remaining size that can't fit into its remaining positions. This is equivalent to the simple calculation *range.max - current position + 1 > range.size* (which can probably be simplified, but I think it's most understandable in this form). Remove each element from its range as it is selected. Remove each range from your list as it is emptied (optional; iterating an empty range will yield no candidates. That's a poor explanation, so lets do one of our examples from the question. Note that `C(-:-)` has been updated to the sanitized `C(1:5)` as described in above.

```
Input order
E(1:1)    C(1:5)    B(1:5)    A(4:4)    D(2:3)
Built ranges (min:max) <remaining capacity> [elements]
(1:1)0[E] (4:4)0[A] (2:3)1[D] (1:5)3[C,B]
```

Find best for 1

```
  Consider (1:1), best element from its list is E
  Consider further ranges?
    range.max - current position + 1 > range.size ?
    range.max = 1; current position = 1; range.size = 1;
    1 - 1 + 1 > 1 = false; do not consider subsequent ranges
Remove E from range, add to output list
```

Find best for 2; current range list is:

```
(4:4)0[A] (2:3)1[D] (1:5)3[C,B]
  Consider (4:4); skip it because it is not eligible for position 2
  Consider (2:3); best element is D
  Consider further ranges?
     3 - 2 + 1 > 1 = true; check next range
  Consider (2:5); best element is B
End of range list; remove B from range, add to output list
```

An added simplifying factor is that the capacities do not need to be updated or the ranges reordered. An item is only removed if the rest of the higher-sorted ranges would not be disturbed by doing so. The remaining capacity is never checked after the initial sort.

Find best for 3; output is now `E`, `B`; current range list is:

```
(4:4)0[A] (2:3)1[D] (1:5)3[C]
  Consider (4:4); skip it because it is not eligible for position 3
  Consider (2:3); best element is D
  Consider further ranges?
     same as previous check, but current position is now 3
     3 - 3 + 1 > 1 = false; don't check next range
Remove D from range, add to output list
```

Find best for 4; output is now `E`, `B`, `D`; current range list is:

```
(4:4)0[A] (1:5)3[C]
  Consider (4:4); best element is A
  Consider further ranges?
     4 - 4 + 1 > 1 = false; don't check next range
Remove A from range, add to output list
```

Output is now `E`, `B`, `D`, `A` and there is one element left to be checked, so it gets appended to the end. This is the output list we desired to have.

This build process is the longest part. At its core, it's a straightforward *n<sup>2</sup>* selection sorting algorithm. The range constraints only work to shorten the inner loop and there is no loopback or recursion; but the worst case <sup>(*I think*)</sup> is still *sum*<sub>*i* = 0</sub> <sup>*n*</sup>(*n - i*), which is [*n<sup>2</sup>/2 - n/2*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%20-%20i%2C%20from%20i%20to%20n).

The detection step comes into play by not excluding a candidate range if the current position is beyond the end of that ranges max position. You have to track the range your best candidate came from in order to remove it, so when you do the removal, just check if the position you're extracting the candidate for is greater than that ranges `endPosition`.

I have several other counter-examples that foiled my earlier algorithms, including a nice example that shows several over-constraint detections on the same input list and also how the final output is closest to the optimal as the constraints will allow. In the mean time, please post any optimizations you can see and especially any counter examples where this algorithm makes an objectively incorrect choice (i.e. arrives at an invalid or suboptimal output when one exists).

---

I'm not going to accept this answer, because I specifically asked if it could be done in better than *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. I haven't wrapped my head around the constraints satisfaction approach in @DaveGalvin's answer yet and I've never done a maximum flow problem, but I thought this might be helpful for others to look at.

Also, I discovered the best way to come up with valid test data is to start with a valid list and randomize it: for 0 -> i, create a random value and constraints such that min < i < max. (Again, posting it because it took me longer than it should have to come up with and others might find it helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

Not likely*. I assume you mean average run time of O(n log n) in-place, non-stable, off-line. Most Sorting algorithms that improve on bubble sort average run time of O(n^2) like [tim sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) rely on the assumption that comparing 2 elements in a sub set will produce the same result in the super set. A slower variant of Quicksort would be a good approach for your range constraints. The worst case won't change but the average case will likely decrease and the algorithm will have the extra constraint of a valid sort existing.

Is ... O(n log n) sort is not guaranteed to find a valid order?

All popular sort algorithms I am aware of are guaranteed to find an order so long as there constraints are met. Formal analysis (concrete proof) is on each sort algorithems wikepedia page.

Is there other existing research on this class of problem?

Yes; there are [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_science_journals) journals like IJCSEA with sorting research.

*but that depends on your average data set.